# What IDEs, editors and tools are available for ClojureScript development?

Tags: clojure, ide, clojurescript

It has been a year since the first announcement of ClojureScript. I haven't been using ClojureScript in production, but am considering using the technology in an upcoming project. What is the current status of IDE and tooling support for ClojureScript. Here are the IDEs, editors and tools and I am aware of:

- [ClojureScript REPL, browser-connected REPL](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/wiki/The-REPL-and-Evaluation-Environments)
- [ClojureScript Emacs setup with two REPLs](https://github.com/brentonashworth/one/wiki/Emacs)
- [lein-clojurescript](https://github.com/bartonj/lein-clojurescript) Leiningen plugin for ClojuresSript compilation.
- [lein-cljsbuild](https://github.com/emezeske/lein-cljsbuild) Leiningen plugin for automatically compiling ClojureScript files when they are modified.
- [CLJS Watcher](https://github.com/ibdknox/cljs-watch)
- [Light Table IDE](http://www.chris-granger.com/2012/08/17/light-table-reaches-010/) Promising and innovative new Clojure/ClojureScript IDE which just reached 0.1.0.

There are probably a couple of project or tools which are missing on this list. I haven't seen any integration into one of the major IDEs, and I can imagine that the majority of people working on ClojureScript are using Emacs. I am fine with using Emacs, but not every developer will like the idea of using Emacs. Are there any tools or IDE extensions missing in this list, maybe even tools which have been used in larger projects?

Comment: Personally I like ClojureScript a lot. It's a fantastic concept, and it amazes me how much cool software and tools the Clojure folks manage to  release. I'd be interested in improving the ClojureScript mode in Emacs, since I've started doing a bit of Elisp development myself.

Comment: Luke Amdor had been working on http://github.com/rubbish/clojurescript-mode, but that repository is offline now, although the Elisp file can still be downloaded here: http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/clojurescript-mode Does anyone know why the code is offline on Github now?

Comment: `not every developer will like the idea of using Emacs` They will! I'd find it very hard to be open-minded enough to try out cljs but not for emacs. Provided sufficient argumentation and a good set of defaults this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I never was in the situation to try to get a team member to use Emacs instead of something like IntelliJ or Eclipse. But you are right, if someone is open enough to use ClojureScript, they'll probably be open enough to use Emacs as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I use La Clojure with intellij. i think for the most part you are on your own, except for syntax highlighting though. You could also try Lighttable however, which is a kickstarter based Clojurescript Web IDE.

Comment: Thanks, and yes, I've tried Light Table since the first test version. It's a very exciting approach to an IDE, and I'll be more than happy to use it once it has been released as beta.

Answer (score 3):

Haven't tried this yet, but it looks promising: http://www.acooke.org/cute/Clojurescr0.html.
This is very simple method for enabling Clojurescript editing in [IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/). Given that La Clojure plugin is very good, I guess IDEA will be friendly to Clojurescript code too.